# how can i sort the table in while loop?

Tags: php, html, mysql

someone can help me to sort this table by calculated $changepercentage please.

My table has more than 1000 records and it's uploaded by date order . 
I tried arsort() , SORT() when it's echo but `PHP` says it's not an array but a string.

I have tried `mysqli_fetch_array()` also but no luck.

need your kind help.

There is an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3fbe9/5) available.

```
clo_prices (table)  
date        |  name   |   cl_price |
2015-09-15  |  AAA    |    10      |
2015-09-15  |  BAA    |    20      |
2015-09-15  |  ABA    |    30      |
2015-09-16  |  AAA    |    86      |
2015-09-16  |  BAA    |    65      |
2015-09-16  |  ABA    |    33      |

 price_list (table)
 date       | name     | volume    | last |
 2015-09-15 | AAA      | 6655245   | 56   |
 2015-09-15 | ABA      | 5666      | 65   |
 2015-09-15 | AAB      | 1333      | 33   |
 2015-09-16 | AAA      | 112365    | 56   |
 2015-09-16 | ABA      | 23131     | 8    |
 2015-09-16 | AAB      | 23330     | 12   |
 2015-09-16 | ABB      | 2323122   | 60   |  
 2015-09-16 | ACB      | 21222     | 99   |

 Desired Result

 date       | company    | closing  | volume    | Change % |
 2015-09-16 | AAA        | 56       | 6655245   | 66       |
 2015-09-16 | ABA        | 65       | 5666      | 9.7      |
 2015-09-16 | ACB        | 69       | 1333      | 7        |
 2015-09-16 | AAB        | 33       | 112365    | 3.2      |
```

---

```
$queryTMG = "SELECT price_list.date,price_list.name, price_list.last, price_list.volume, clo_prices.date, clo_prices.name, clo_prices.cl_price
                FROM price_list 
                INNER JOIN clo_prices
                ON price_list.name = clo_prices.name 
                WHERE price_list.date= '$dateT' AND clo_prices.date = '$dateT' ORDER BY name LIMIT 10 ";

$queryPMG = "SELECT price_list.date, price_list.name, price_list.last, price_list.volume, clo_prices.date, clo_prices.name, clo_prices.cl_price
                FROM price_list 
                INNER JOIN clo_prices
                ON price_list.name = clo_prices.name 
                WHERE price_list.date= '$dateT' AND clo_prices.date = '$dateP' ORDER BY name LIMIT 10";

$resultTMG = mysqli_query($dbc, $queryTMG) or die (mysqli_error());
$resultPMG = mysqli_query($dbc, $queryPMG) or die (mysqli_error());


echo '<table  cellpadding = 15 border =1>';
echo '<tr>  
        <th>Company</th>    
        <th>Closing</th> 
        <th>Volume</th> 
        <th>Change %</th> 
        </tr>';
while($rowTMG = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultTMG) AND $rowPMG = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultPMG))
{
        echo '<tr> <td>'. $rowTMG['name']. '</td>'; 
        echo '<td>'. $rowTMG['last']. '</td>';
        echo '<td align = "right">'. $volumeTMG = number_format($rowTMG['volume']). '</td>';
        echo '<td align = "right">'.  $changeprecentage = number_format((( $rowTMG['cl_price'] - $rowPMG['cl_price'] ) / $rowTMG['cl_price']), 2, '.', '' ). '</td> </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: hi Drew,

Thanks . actually i use all the columns in "clo_prices"  table but yeah only few columns in "price_list" table . will edit that part :) 

yes i can order my its "name" but how can that help pls ?

Comment: no Drew, there are 1000s of records in my tables :/

Comment: here i prune it to what columns i need . my issue is i cant get the top-ten data in of change-percentage :(

Comment: sorry , what do you mean ?

Comment: ok , got it . pls check now

Comment: thx. Now, we need **Desired Results** (view/table/results concept) in question via [edit]. Keeping in mind you are showing limit 10 and I dont know what that means

Comment: so if you put the **Desired Results** up there, and describe well what LIMIT 10 means knowing that you have 1000's of rows, you will probably get an answer.

Comment: done, i think now you have a clear image in my problem :) 
thanks

Comment: what is the basis for AAA having those two numbers and having an accurate 12% chg ?

Comment: its just random data . just typed.

what i want is 
changePrecentage = ((cl_price of  2015-09-16 AAA - cl_price of 2015-09-15 AAA)  / cl_price of 2015-09-16) * 100% 
 then sort it to the highest & lowest 10 by its changePrecentage

Comment: so, as for a description for someone actually coding it, you want max date minus min date, if there are hundreds in there for AAA or any given grouping

Comment: no, i want a change(difference) all "names" on given $dateT cl_price - $dateP cl_price, then the highest 10 changePrecentage & the lowest 10 of chanePrecentage 

echo '<td align = "right">'.  $changeprecentage = number_format((( $rowTMG['cl_price'] - $rowPMG['cl_price'] ) / $rowTMG['cl_price']), 2, '.', '' ). '</td> </tr>';